# Moving a node in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I have a SCNNode and I want it to be in a specific position by default.  I tried to set the position from .dae file, but it's not saving. Can some give me a hint how can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. In your title you say you want to move a node, but in your question itself you say that you want the node at a specific position. Do you want to move the node to a default position or do you want to have it there at launch?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, my english is kinda bad. I want it to be in a specific position when I start aplication.

Comment: No problem. I've answered your question.

Comment: And, is there any method that lets me rotate it by x,y,z axis and place it however I want?

Comment: Yes, but I think you should read the documentation or some tutorials by yourself to get a basic-knowledge: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the position like that:

```
yourNode.position = SCNVector3Make(yourXValue, yourYValue, yourZValue)
```

Call that method when you first start your app.